# How to calculate the amount of offset for a scrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

Does anybody know the ratio of ScrollToHorizontalOffset and ScrollToVerticalOffset to the window size? Is there a rule of thumb?

Given an X,Y I want to center the window on the X,Y, so what would the offsets be? No, this doesn't work:

```
 scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(X);
 scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(Y);
```

Doing some tests it seemed like scrollViewer took about 28 steps to scroll a window that was 2,048 by 2,048.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a thing like rule of thumb.

ScrollView.Extent is the complete size.

ScrollViewer.Viewport is the visible size.

ScrollViewer.VertiacalOffset is the current Y offset value.

ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset is the current X offset value.

Comment: So, if you have an image (2048 x 2048) that is inside a scrollviewer and you have an X,Y, how would you center the scrollviewer on the X,Y?

Comment: Image is 2048x2048 that is the Extent. The visible part is 600x600. If you want to place scrollbar in center just do the math: Y = 2048 / 2 - 600 / 2